# The web environment on iOS devices when scrolling when setting scrollTop results in a white screen

Tags: iphone, scrollview

When a scrollable element is in a fast scrolling state, I wish it could be manually scrolled to the bottom, by setting scrollTop. However, at this point, a white screen appears in the scrolling area. This is normal on PC or Android, just on iOS.

I spent a long time looking for the cause of the problem, but I didn't find it, it seems to be a problem with the browser itself, but I found a solution, adding the style scroll-behavior: smooth; This will make scrolling slow while not having the problem of white screens. But I still want to know the reason behind it.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is not related to your question, and i also want to know the specific reason, just like you. However, since there doesn't seem to be many issues related to this, and in case someone is suffering due to this problem, I would like to share my workaround solution

I'm developing a webview using react-native, and the webview serves a Next.js application. Even though using 'scroll-behavior: smooth' can resolve the issue, if you don't want the smooth scrolling behavior, you can use the following method.

This issue occurs when the scrollTo logic is executed while the scroll is in progress. When the scroll is not in motion and then the scrollTo logic is executed, the problem doesn't occur.

So, the solution is to stop the scroll if it's in progress and then execute scrollTo. As far as I know, in most browsers, the only way to stop a scrolling that's in progress is to use 'overflow-y: hidden.' You can create a function that wraps scrollTo to induce this behavior as follows:

```
const modifiedScrollTo = (element, scrollPos) => {
  if(platform === ios) {
     element.style.overflowY = 'hidden';
     element.scrollTo({ top: scrollPos });
     element.style.overflowY = 'scroll';
  } else {
     element.scrollTo({ top: scrollPos });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is when a scrollable element is in a fast scrolling state, the browser might not be able to render content fast enough as the scroll position changes rapidly. This can lead to a temporary blank space appearing, which shows up as a white screen.

The solution is using debounce when handle scroll event.